# What implementations allow me to detect failed HMAC validations to detect active attacks?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, implementation, hmac, hmacsha1

I'm trying to bring awareness around the need for [authentication with encryption](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Authentication-Forgotten-Predominant.html) by using software to alert and report on failed [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) verification attempts, and sharing the results with middle management.

I'm not a cryptographer, but I see the value in a proper implementation.  Ideally I'd like to create a report that says X attacks were prevented.

Is this a valid idea, or is it overly simplistic?  If not, where should I start in implementing it?  (Low level AES, PGP, etc?)

Comment: Perhaps this should be tagged "active-attack" as well?  I don't have the rep, so please edit if you agree.

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you are trying to do ... do have a server which provides some login function, and want to log the failed authentication attempts? (This is not really cryptography-related.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann , I'm not interested in a Serverfault type of question, but rather to track Message Authentication Code (MAC) violations or anything that indicates integrity was broken.

Comment: A good protocol (respective implementation) should break down the connection when a MAC is wrong. (At least if you are using something connection-based, for a single-packet protocol you might simply throw away the packet.) Then it comes down on logging/counting the number of connections which were not finished normally.

Comment: Thanks @PaŭloEbermann , I'm looking for names of the protocol implementations (DLL, product, vendor) that would expose this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [C# MAC code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that could be modified to alert or log when authentication fails.  This is an incomplete sample that shouldn't be used AS-IS since many other details need to be considered before implementing  `Authenticate-then-Encrypt (AtE)` or `Encrypt-then-Authenticate  (EtA)`

It would be nice to know what performance counter, log file, or DLL `exception` relates to this error.  I'll be investigating BouncyCastle to see where the corresponding exception is.

```
// Compares the key in the source file with a new key created for the data portion of the file. If the keys 
// compare the data has not been tampered with.
public static bool VerifyFile(byte[] key, String sourceFile)
{
    bool err = false;
    // Initialize the keyed hash object. 
    using (HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(key))
    {
        // Create an array to hold the keyed hash value read from the file.
        byte[] storedHash = new byte[hmac.HashSize / 8];
        // Create a FileStream for the source file.
        using (FileStream inStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // Read in the storedHash.
            inStream.Read(storedHash, 0, storedHash.Length);
            // Compute the hash of the remaining contents of the file.
            // The stream is properly positioned at the beginning of the content, 
            // immediately after the stored hash value.
            byte[] computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(inStream);
            // compare the computed hash with the stored value

            for (int i = 0; i < storedHash.Length; i++)
            {
                if (computedHash[i] != storedHash[i])
                {
                    err = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hash values differ! Signed file has been tampered with!");
        // 
        // 
        // <-------- This is where the MAC alerting would go
        // 
        // 

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hash values agree -- no tampering occurred.");
        return true;
    }

} //end VerifyFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Any method where the authenticator can't determine if a password is valid just from the information he has will do. The only schemes that wouldn't let you alert and report failed authentication attempts were ones where an authentication attempt could bypass the server.

For example, if the authenticator is an AES key (which can be generated from a password or passphrase), simply challenge the authenticating agent to encrypt or decrypt a random 128-bit string. All an attacker gets is a random 128-bit string. So to try to see if a particular password works, he'll have to send a response back to you, and you can log an incorrect one.

Comment: Are there any higher level implementations that will log this event so I can report on it?

Comment: I think you'd have a hard time finding an implementation that didn't. Logging access failures is pretty standard. Just don't choose a mechanism that makes undetectable failures possible.